# Regex to match specific file format and empty strings

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to use regex to match a file in the following format:

```
FILTER
<data>
ORDER
<data>
```

Now, the `<data>` part is the one that I need to extract, and that would be really simple, except I have the following complications:

1) This pattern can be repeated (no line breaks inbetween)

2) The `<data>`s could be not there.

In particular, this file is OK:

```
FILTER
test1
ORDER
test2
FILTER
test3
ORDER
FILTER
ORDER
```

And should give me the following groups:

"test1", "test2", "test3", "", "", ""

The regex that I already tried is: `(?:FILTER\n(.*)\nORDER\n(.*))*`

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/bT2rD7/1) is the test on regex101.

I am pretty new to regex, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would simplify it to: [`FILTER(.*?)ORDER(.*?)(?=FILTER|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/bT2rD7/2) and then strip newlines accordingly. Note that you need to include the `s` modifier to match newlines with the dot `.`.

Comment: @HamZa That doesn't quite work... Also I don't really understand it https://regex101.com/r/bT2rD7/3

Comment: You added the `m` modifier to my regex which will change the whole meaning. Remove it. (I made my regex clickable?)

Comment: @HamZa oh, it looks good now. Thanks :D

Comment: @sadfsasdfasdf: Please note that my unrolled regex is potentially more efficient than [`FILTER(.*?)ORDER(.*?)(?=FILTER|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/xI1yT7/1).

Comment: I have added another solution and modified my previous one. Still, my solution looks the most efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a lazy-dot matching + tempered greedy token based regex:

```
(?s)FILTER(.*?)ORDER((?:(?!FILTER).)*)
           ^-^       ^--------------^
```

Use a DOTALL modifier with this regex. Here is a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY2yY0/3). The `.*?` matches any character but as few as possilbe, thus, matching up to the first `ORDER`. The `(?:(?!FILTER).)*` tempered greedy token matches any text that is not `FILTER`. It is a kind of a negated character class synonym for multicharacter sequences.

You can unroll it as follows:

```
FILTER([^O]*(?:O(?!RDER)[^O]*)*)ORDER([^F]*(?:F(?!ILTER)[^F]*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fY2yY0/5) (and this regex does not require a DOTALL mode).

```
String s = "FILTER\ntest1\nORDER\ntest2\nFILTER\ntest3\nORDER\nFILTER\nORDER";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)FILTER(.*?)ORDER((?:(?!FILTER).)*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        results.add(matcher.group(1).trim());
    } 
    if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        results.add(matcher.group(2).trim());
    } 
} 
System.out.println(results);  // => [test1, test2, test3, , , ]
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/z28Meq)

**If you need to make sure the `FILTER` and `ORDER` delimiter strings appear as individual lines, just use `^` and `$` around them and add MULTILINE modifier** (so that `^` could match the beginning of a line and `$` could match the end of the line):

```
(?sm)^FILTER$(.*?)^ORDER$((?:(?!^FILTER$).)*)
 ^^^^
```

See [another regex](https://regex101.com/r/fY2yY0/6).

Comment: This looks great, but what do you mean by "unrolling"?

Comment: Why have `!FILTER` after `FILTER`, but not have `!ORDER` after `ORDER`? Also, you don't limit to full line testing, so a value of `abcFILTER` will cause havoc.

Comment: @Andreas: *This pattern can be repeated (**no line breaks inbetween**)*. There is only one ORDER inside, and thus the second tempered greedy token should not jump over the starting delimiter which is `FILTER` here. With a tempered greedy token, we can add word boundaries and other restrictions. Just need more feedback from OP.

Comment: @sadfsasdfasdf: If the current regex works for you, here is an unrolled version: [`FILTER([^FO]*(?:F(?!ILTER)[^FO]*|O(?!RDER)[^FO]*)*)ORDER([^F]*(?:F(?!ILTER)[^F]*)*)`](https://regex101.com/r/fY2yY0/2). It does not require DOTALL modifer to match across lines.

Comment: I think question is pretty clear. `FILTER` and `ORDER` must be tokens on separate lines, i.e. `(?m)^FILTER$` and `(?m)^ORDER$`. Also, format is `FILTER <data> ORDER <data>`, so you cannot have `FILTER FILTER` without `ORDER` in between. Your regex doesn't follow there rules.

Comment: With your updated answer, the last regex is almost there, but the captured `<data>` is wrong, since you capture the newlines too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew A piece of advice: [Keep It Simple Stupid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). The "unrolled" regex is massive and plain confusing for most developers. One needs to have a really good reason for micro optimization. See also http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: HamZa, it is not premature. I deal with hundreds gigabytes of data every day and prefer to play it safe - **always**. OP never showed real life examples, so an unrolled version (especially in Java where stack overflow issues are not infrequent) can prove the only right direction. Andreas, the `trim()` is used in code to remove the redundant whitespace from both start and end of the captured values, see the code demo.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following regex :

```
FILTER(?:\n(?!ORDER)(.*))?\nORDER(?:\n(?!FILTER)(.*))?
```

You can test it on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aB3xW0/3)

Comment: I've just updated it to remove the need for a trailing line feed, is it better now?

Comment: Wiktor's answer works more like needed, yours doesn't give the empty strings.

Comment: Hu? It does give the empty strings, with your exemple group 2 is empty in the second match and both group 1 and 2 are empty in the last one.